# Display in one column the monthly sum and in another column the value of the last date per month

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Data Source**

| event_date | credits_collected | credits_redeemed | credits_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-08 | 900 | 700 | 200 |
| 2020-02-15 | 500 | 300 | 400 |
| 2020-02-20 | 100 | 250 | 250 |
| 2020-03-19 | 600 | 850 | 0 |
| 2020-04-03 | 450 | 130 | 320 |

**Target report:**

| event_month | credits_collected | credits_redeemed | credits_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 900 | 700 | 200 |
| 2 | 600 | 550 | 250 |
| 3 | 600 | 850 | 0 |
| 4 | 450 | 130 | 320 |

In the report I want to build a **monthly sum** over the columns `credits_collected` and `credits_redeemed`.

Additionally, I want to show the column `credits_balance`.

However, in this column the value of the **last event_date per month** should be displayed

*(as you can see fore example in month = 2)*

I am able to get the monthly sum into my report but I have no idea how I can solve the issue with the last event_date per month.

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this in PowerBI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue with following DAX-Formula:

```
credits_balance = CALCULATE(MAX(Tabelle1[credits_balance]),ENDOFMONTH(Tabelle1[event_date]))
```